# Splitting into groups and exploding pyspark array type column

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have static lists `group_1` and `group_2`:

```
group_1 = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
group_2 = [h,i,j,k]
```

I have pyspark dataframe `df1` as shown below.

**Example1:**

df1:

```
+-----+----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
|id   |array1                                  |array2                                   |
+-----+----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
|id1  |[a,b,c,d,group_1,group_2]               |[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k]                  |
+-----+----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

output_df:

```
+-----+-------------------|-------------------|
|id   |col1               |col2               |
+-----+-------------------|-------------------|
|id1  |[a,b,c,d]          |[a,b,c,d]          |
|id1  |[e,f,g]            |group_1            |
|id1  |[h,i,j,k]          |group_2            |
+-----+-------------------|-------------------|
```

Actually, `array2` column will have elements from `array1` column. That's how my source dataframe (`source_df1`) will be.

If we see `array1` column there are individual elements like `(a,b,c,d)` and also `group_1` and `group_2` elements but all together they are distinct.

Now I want to create pyspark dataframe by exploding such a way that individual and group elements are categorized as shown in `output_df`.

**Example1 Observation:** If we see the output dataframe `output_df`, the second record `group_1` has only `[e,f,g]` because other elements are already part of individual elements.

**Example2:**

source_df1:

```
+-----+----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
|id   |array1                                  |array2                                   |
+-----+----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
|id1  |[a,b,group_1,group_2]                   |[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k]                  |
+-----+----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

output_df:

```
+-----+-------------------|-------------------|
|id   |col1               |col2               |
+-----+-------------------|-------------------|
|id1  |[a,b]              |[a,b]              |
|id1  |[c,d,e,f,g]        |group_1            |
|id1  |[h,i,j,k]          |group_2            |
+-----+-------------------|-------------------|
```

**Example2 Observation:** If we see the output dataframe `output_df`. the second record `group_1` has only `[c,d,e,f,g]` because other elements are already part of individual elements.

Can anyone please help on achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use Spark 2.4+, you can achieve that with some array functions :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


df1 = df.withColumn(
    "individual",
    F.array_except(F.col("array1"), F.array(*[F.lit("group_1"), F.lit("group_2")]))
).withColumn(
    "group_1",
    F.array_except(F.array(*[F.lit(i) for i in group_1]), "individual")
).withColumn(
    "group_2",
    F.array_except(F.array(*[F.lit(i) for i in group_2]), "individual")
).withColumn(
    "array2",
    F.explode(F.array(
        *[
            F.struct(F.array_intersect("array2", "individual").alias("col1"),
                     F.col("individual").cast("string").alias("col2")),
            F.struct(F.array_intersect("array2", "group_1").alias("col1"),
                     F.lit("group_1").alias("col2")),
            F.struct(F.array_intersect("array2", "group_2").alias("col1"),
                     F.lit("group_2").alias("col2"))
        ])
    )
).select("id", "array2.*")

df1.show(truncate=False)

#+---+------------+------------+
#|id |col1        |col2        |
#+---+------------+------------+
#|id1|[a, b, c, d]|[a, b, c, d]|
#|id1|[e, f, g]   |group_1     |
#|id1|[h, i, j, k]|group_2     |
#+---+------------+------------+
```

**Explanations:**

- First, divide `array1` into three arrays: `individual`, `group_1` and `group_2`. Each one contains elements for the corresponding group. Elements from `group_1` and `group_2` that are present in `individual` are removed from those groups.
- Then, using `array_intersect` function get elements from `array2` column that are present in each of the three group arrays created above.
- Finally, explode the new array created above

Note that if you want to verify that `group_1` or `group_2` is present in `array1` column you can use `when` with `array_contains` functions :

```
F.when(
    F.array_contains(F.col("array1"), F.lit("group_1")),
    F.array_except(F.array(*[F.lit(i) for i in group_1]), "individual")
)
```

In the example, I supposed it is always present in `array1`.